# Why does NSObject get deallocated while it presents its UIViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, memory-management, uiviewcontroller, nsobject

An `NSObject` presents a view controller:

```
class myObject: NSObject {

    var myVC = UIViewController()

    func present() {
        let rootVC = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow!.rootViewController
        rootVC.presentViewController(myVC, animated: animated, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Why does `myObject` get deallocated (deinit is called) when `myVC` is presented and still visible on the screen? Shouldn't it stay allocated because `myVC` is its property?

**Update:** The effective problem I face is that `myVC` shows a view with controls whose delegate is `myObject`. Because `myObject` is deallocated the controls cannot call the delegate anymore because I reference the delegate as `weak`. However when I have a strong reference to the delegate `myObject` stays allocated and the delegate gets called. But it smells fishy to use a strong reference for the delegate.

Comment: delegates are usually weak references, so the behavior is expected. The presented controller doesn't own the delegate!

Comment: Architecture problem. Your object is the owner of your controller but nobody owns the object, therefore it gets deallocated.

Comment: Probably because nobody holds reference to MyObject... this is wrong way of presenting/dismissing UIViewController, why you wrapping it to your MyObject? You should show one viewController from another instance of ViewController without any mediators and you will not have issues with delegation

Comment: Thanks guys, that makes sense of course. I guess I will make myObject a singleton to resolve this. In my case `myObject` configures the view controller, but the configuration is so complex that I rather not have it in the presenting view controller's code.

Comment: if you want do this oke, but suggest at least to rename myObject to something like DisplayController or something logical

Comment: @Injectios thanks, the names are different of course, I just simplified as an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ARC memory management is based on ownership. Once an object is not owned by any other object, it gets deallocated. There is always a root object which owns all others - the `UIApplication`. The ownership of all objects in the application can be described with a tree:

```
UIApplication
  - UIApplicationDelegate
       - rootViewController
            - child controllers
               - child controllers ...
       - window
            - subviews
               - subviews ...
       - ... other objects
```

You can create other root objects (other ownership trees), of course, e.g. by using singletons.

If you instance is not owned by an object in this hierarchy tree, it gets deallocated. Therefore you should build your ownership hierarchy in a way that controllers are owned only by other controllers, not by custom objects.

If you need a reference to the owner, that's usually the time to use a `weak` reference, to avoid cyclical ownerships.

Also note that `UIViewController` takes some significant memory on the heap so it is not very common to keep references to them once they are not needed. It's more common to create new instances before presenting them (although exceptions exist).

Comment: So what would you recommend to be best practise for a "login view controller" that can get presented at any time throughout the application flow when the user gets logged out? The login view contains buttons that trigger functions in the delegate, currently an NSObject. If I removed the NSObject from the ownership tree I had to move the configuration in every calling view controller. I can only think of replacing myObject with another view controller that does nothing but configuring and presenting the login view controller but that also doesn't seem efficient.

Comment: @Manuel I think that's something you should put into the application delegate (e.g. using a category) or to the root view controller. Root view controller is usually the place that handles such things. You are actually accessing that controller in your code.